# Debugging in RubyMine with Pow as a server - Ruby 2.1.1 + Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, ruby-debug, rack-pow

I have started using RubyMine 6. I am working on a Rails 4, Ruby 2.1.1 project.
I am not able to find how to debug into RubyMine with Pow as a server.

Can you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: I was using the debugger of RubyMine, but then I found that the standard debugger a better alternative.

Answer (score 15):

I am able to debug from RubyMine using the remote debugging. I'm using RubyMine 6, Rails 3, Ruby 2.1.1.

1. First create a `.powenv` file and add:

   > export RUBY_DEBUG_PORT=1234
   >
   > export POW_WORKERS=1
2. Add the following gems to your `Gemfile`:

   > gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
   >
   > gem 'debase'
3. Create a new initializer `start_debugger.rb` and add the following content:

   ```
   if ENV['RUBY_DEBUG_PORT']
     require 'ruby-debug-ide'
     Debugger.start_server nil, ENV['RUBY_DEBUG_PORT'].to_i
   end
   ```
4. Now in RubyMine you should be able to add a new run configuration using the default template for `Ruby remote debug` setting the local and remote folders to the root of your Rails app.
5. Now restart pow and attempt to connect. You should see it connected in the debugger pane.

Comment: Fantastic answer. This works really well. I'd like to point out for step 4 that you also have to set both the local and remote ports to 1234. One of the ports has a different default, so it didn't work for me at first.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can just use Pow to proxy yourapp.dev domain to your localhost:3000 by

```
echo 3000 > ~/.pow/yourapp
```

And then, access yourapp.dev and debug your app in Rubymine as normal